# Toad for Oracle, Editing ID Column to be an auto-increment ID

Tags: oracle, toad

I work with `Toad for Oracle 12.1` for my database. I have a Table called `TBLEMPLOYEE` which already contain some data in it and having `Column Name` called `ID` whose data values are increasing from 1 to N.

```
ID  Name    Gender  DateOfBirth Type
------------------------------------
1   Mark    Male    10/10/1982  1
2   Mary    Female  11/11/1981  2
3   Esther  Female  12/12/1984  2
4   Matthew Male    9/9/1983    1
5   John    Male    5/5/1985    1
6   Luke    Male    6/6/1986    1
```

Now I want to change the `Column ID` such that it will have auto-incremented ID when I add a new data to the `Table`.

I know that in Toad we can do it when we create a `New Table` with that behavior. For instance, using `Create Table` and in the newly created `Column`, we could set `Default / Virtual / Identity` settings as `Identity`:

[image]

And `Toad` will show a UI with bunch of settings to do that:

[image]

And will be automatically translated to something like:

```
(START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 CACHE 20 NOCYCLE ORDER NOKEEP)
```

In the `Default / Virtual / Identity` settings.

But I can't seem to do the same when I do `Alter Table` instead of `Create Table`.

[image]

Why is that so?

And since I already have some data in the `TBLEMPLOYEE`, I want to avoid creating a new table and re-inserting the data if possible.

How can I do that?

This is the current SQL script (if this may help):

```
ALTER TABLE MYSCHEMA.TBLEMPLOYEE
 DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE;

DROP TABLE MYSCHEMA.TBLEMPLOYEE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.TBLEMPLOYEE
(
  ID            NUMBER                          NOT NULL,
  NAME          VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  GENDER        VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
  DATEOFBIRTH   DATE,
  EMPLOYEETYPE  INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
)
TABLESPACE USERS
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;

ALTER TABLE MYSCHEMA.TBLEMPLOYEE ADD (
  PRIMARY KEY
  (ID)
  USING INDEX
    TABLESPACE USERS
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   2
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                PCTINCREASE      0
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
               )
  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your sequence should start with the max value + 1 from the table e.g.

```
(START WITH 7 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 CACHE 20 NOCYCLE ORDER NOKEEP)
```

If you want to automatically populate the value for the Id and you're not running on Oracle 12c, I suggest you  to use a trigger

```
drop sequence seq_mytest_id;

truncate table my_test_t;

drop table my_test_t;

create table my_test_t (id number, string varchar2(30));

-- prepopulate with fixed values for the id
insert into my_test_t(id, string) values (1,'test');
insert into my_test_t(id, string) values (2,'test');
insert into my_test_t(id, string) values (3,'test');
insert into my_test_t(id, string) values (4,'test');
insert into my_test_t(id, string) values (5,'test');
insert into my_test_t(id, string) values (6,'test');

commit;

--Now create the sequence and the trigger for automatically 
--populating the ID column
create sequence seq_mytest_id start with 7 increment by 1 nocycle nocache;

create trigger t_mytest_bi before insert on  my_test_t for each row
begin
  select seq_mytest_id.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;
/

-- Test the trigger
insert into my_test_t(string) values ('test');

insert into my_test_t(string) values ('test2');


commit;

select * from my_test_t;
```

If you're running on Oracle 12c you can define your column as an identity column

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1

Hope it helps,
R

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I got the following error - any idea? ALTER TABLE MYSCHEMA.TBLEMPLOYEE
MODIFY(ID  DEFAULT (START WITH 7 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 CACHE 20 NOCYCLE ORDER NOKEEP))
Error at line 3
ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: I think that what you want to do is to redefine the sequence. For this you should probably re-create the sequence 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm#i2067093

Comment: That's what I *don't* want to do actually... If possible, I want to keep the current data intact... :( see my question: "And since I already have some data in the TBLEMPLOYEE, I want to avoid creating a new table and re-inserting the data if possible."

Comment: Well... by dropping the sequence you're not dropping the table i.e.  "your data stays the same" 
If you're using Oracle 12c I suggest you to read 
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1

Comment: Again, if you're on Oracle 12c, check the sequence name for the Idendity column and recreate it

`SELECT a.name AS table_name,
       b.name AS sequence_name
FROM   sys.idnseq$ c
       JOIN obj$ a ON c.obj# = a.obj#
       JOIN obj$ b ON c.seqobj# = b.obj#
Where a.name = 'TBLEMPLOYEE'`

Comment: Ok, I think I really screw up this time... I ended up losing the data while re-sequencing my Table. Thanks for your help anyway...